Clear not working. "clear: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by clear)"
clear not working in terminal. I installed homebrew in linux and uninstalled NodeJS (to install it back again using brew). However, when I was trying to check if the node package was still there, I ran into this error:
clear: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by clear)
clear: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.33' not found (required by /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/ncurses/6.5/lib/libncursesw.so.6)

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 version, and I've not installed much of anything. Is there a way to resolve this.
I tried updating and upgrading he system, still no luck. Is there something I am missing? Thank you

You seem to have a messed up system. If possible just reinstall he OS. You don't need homebrew/brew in Ubuntu to install nodejs, instead follow https://github.com/nodesource/distributions?tab=readme-ov-file#using-ubuntu-nodejs-22 to install it using curl bash and apt.

brew/homebrew seem to be very much intended as a macOS thing, I have never seen it used on any other platform: "The missing package manager for macOS" https://github.com/Homebrew/brew

@masterxilo you missed the "(or Linux)" at the end. Homebrew is frequently used on Linux as well; Linuxbrew used to be a separate project but it was eventually merged into Homebrew.
